# Android studio installation warning : A folder failed to be moved

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the android studio today and I got a problem with the SDK manager:

[image]

I've followed this guide:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

When I install the -

> ARM EABI v7a System Image

I get this error. I tried to disable the antivirus but its still doesn't work. 
Hope for answers, thanks.

Comment: tried with admin rights?

Comment: What do you mean? run as administrator?

Comment: yes, thats what i meant. I have similar problems at my company with installations, also with android-studio and sdk. Usually run as admin solves most of those issues.

Comment: run the SDK manager as administrator? or run  the android studio as administrator?

Comment: Try Run SDK manager as administrator will solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have similar problems at my company with installations, also with android-studio and sdk. Usually run as admin solves most of those issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Android Studio or Eclipse.
2. Open folder "C:\Users\YourPC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools"
3. Run "android.bat" as Administrator.

Now you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse close eclipse and run android sdk manager as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. The **solutions** that i have done is as follows :

The problem is with **temp** folder in android sdk folder. i have changed the folder name from **temp** to **temp1**.

**Now it is working properly for me.**

I hope it will work for you also...

Answer (score 0):

Delete **TOOLS** folder.
in temp folder there might a zip that you have downloaded. unzip it and copy tools folder and paste it in android sdk home folder.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse - **Close** the Android SDK Manager

Then - go to the directory - named where `android-sdk` are saved by default, by default, in my PC, the location is `C:\Users\username\android-sdks`.

In this folder, look for a temp folder and tools folder - make copy of tools folder beforehand. In temp folder, you will find  zip folder similar like `tools_R25.zip` (I donot remember the exact name, but look for similar name), open the folder, inside you see a folder named tools -- now

Unzip the content of the tools folder inside `android-sdks/tools`, and start android SDK Manager again as `administrator`.

Comment: sorry, but the question is for AS,